# Inner tree view elements not visible in chrome, visible in IE11

Tags: html, css

I have a window that contains a tree view of departments and subdepartments. Clicking an arrow next to the department opens up the tree to show subdepartments.

When I expand the tree and inspect the elements, the elements that are not visible are in the DOM but aren't being rendered. Below is the portion of the HTML containing the tree structure, and I've commented where the visibility stops.

```
<-- Parent Node is Visible -->
<div id="parenttree" style="display: block;">
   <ul class="tree">
      <li id="li_g-test_dept">
         <div id="div_g-test_dept" class="parentfloater">
            <a id="link_g-test_dept" name="Test Dept *" class="row2">
            <span id="span_9|g-test_dept" class="expandedNode" style="display: block;">
            </span>
            <span style="float: left; width: 30px; display: block;">
            <img src="/console/images/static/groupsicon.gif" border="0">
            </span>
            <span style="float: left; width: 250px; display: block;">Test Dept *</span>
            <span style="float: left; width: 80px; display: block;">0</span>
            <span style="float: left; width: 50px; display: block;">1</span>
            <span style="float: left; width: 100px; display: block;">Global</span></a>
         </div>
         <div id="9|g-test_dept" style="display: block;">

<-- Begin of Child Node, elements not visible -->

            <ul class="tree">
               <li id="li_g-test_subdept">
                  <div id="div_g-test_subdept" class="floater"><a id="link_g-test_subdept" name="Test SubDept **"><span id="span_11|g-test_subdept" class="collapsedNode" style="display: block;"></span><span style="float: left; width: 30px; display: block;">
                     <img src="/console/images/static/subdepartmenticon.gif" border="0"></span><span style="float: left; width: 250px; display: block;">Test SubDept **</span><span style="float: left; width: 80px; display: block;">0</span><span style="float: left; width: 50px; display: block;">1</span><span style="float: left; width: 100px; display: block;">Global</span></a>
                  </div>
                  <div id="11|g-test_subdept" style="display: none;"></div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li id="li_g-vstusers">

<-- Childless Parent Node Visible -->

         <div id="div_g-vstusers" class="parentfloater"><a id="link_g-vstusers" name="VSTUsers *"><span style="float: left; width: 12px; display: block; height: 15px;"></span><span style="float: left; width: 30px; display: block;"><img src="/console/images/static/groupsicon.gif" border="0"></span><span style="float: left; width: 250px; display: block;">VSTUsers *</span><span style="float: left; width: 80px; display: block;">1</span><span style="float: left; width: 50px; display: block;">0</span><span style="float: left; width: 100px; display: block;">Global</span></a></div>
         <div id="10|g-vstusers" style="display: none;"></div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Edit: The inner contents are visible after setting the style of the divs to 'table' or 'table-cell'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent node div element needs to have its style set to `display: table-cell` in order for the tree structure to display.